# Pass arguments to Bootstrap modal manually opened

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How do I pass arguments to modal which is opened manually?

$('#myModal').modal('show');

I can't seem to find it from its documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: what are you doing detailly?

Comment: Is https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript your reference?

Comment: @WeiYuan yes, that one.

Comment: What are you trying to do???? No one knows... Technically, you can pass arguments to any function you want `$('#modal').modal('show', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...)` see...? But what are you trying to make happen?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @TJBlackman I want to pass some data like message, and get this when modal is shown. As of now, my solution is I declared global variable. Set the value of variable before showing the modal and display the variable value in the modal.

Comment: @TJBlackman, in your example, how do I get 1 through 6 when the modal is shown? $('#myModal').modal().on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { // how do I get 1..6 here?});

Comment: I don't think you can without editing the Bootstrap code itself. Mostly likely, there is a better way to do whatever you're trying to do. Ask a question about how to accomplish the end-goal, because passing in params is probably not the best way to do it.